# Log only database-changing queries

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there a way to tell sqlalchemy to log queries, but only those that change the state of the database (in particular `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`)?

I would like to keep a tally of all the changes made to the content of a mostly static database, but I do not want every web access to it be logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQLAlchemy-Continuum for this..its pretty cool...see the documentation to use - https://sqlalchemy-continuum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

You can track all modification of your database with this.

Comment: continuum looks promising even though I was originally looking for a very low-level way, but it leads to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39205191/1274613).