# How to use the User column for transactions?

Tags: sqlalchemy-continuum

I got a recommendation to use sqlalchemy-continuum, which seems to do very much what I want out of the box.

By default, the ORM assumes that there is a user column. I do indeed want to save originators of an edit, but the [documentation](https://sqlalchemy-continuum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=user&check_keywords=yes&area=default) only says “This is how you specify a User class”, without saying anything about how to specify such an object when actually using versioned tables.

How do I specify the User responsible for a transaction?
Is there a similar way to add a commit message/reason/citation (a VARCHAR) to each transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can get the user from some global scope (like flask.g or flask.request), you can create a plugin, implementing the `transaction_args()` method:

```py
from sqlalchemy_continuum.plugins import Plugin


class UserPlugin(Plugin):

    def transaction_args(self, uow, session):
        return {
            'user_id': get_user_from_globals()
        }
```

See [plugins/flask.py](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-continuum/blob/master/sqlalchemy_continuum/plugins/flask.py) or [pyramid_plugin.py](https://github.com/M4d40/sqlalchemy-continuum/blob/111d943c13d3d3b3a35b008aada6bee8358a0945/sqlalchemy_continuum/plugins/pyramid_plugin.py). You should return primary key value of your User model.

You can save additional data with [TransactionMeta plugin](https://sqlalchemy-continuum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins.html#module-sqlalchemy_continuum.plugins.transaction_meta) in a separate table. There is no documented API for extending the Transaction class itself. It is created by `TransactionFactory`, but that could change in later versions. It is probably a good idea to keep additional data separate.

Answer (score -2):

Use this for native versioning:

```
from sqlalchemy_continuum import make_versioned
make_versioned(options={'native_versioning': True},
               user_cls=None)
```

It creates version tables for each table in db. Whenever there is update in a table, it creates entry in version table for old data.

This creates these new columns: transaction_id,end_transaction_id,operation_type in {orgion_table}_version